# Issue with category's URL

Tags: magento, magento-1.6

I'm implementing a new template for a Magento site.

I have issues with categories URL. I used to access on **http://localhost/category-name.html** but when I changed its parent category, it stopped working, displaying a **404 page**.

I've tried modifying SEO options on Configuration - Catalog and also rewriting indexes on the backend, with no success.

Could it be other reasons why this is happening?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you looked in backend menu: `Products/Url Rewrite Management` to see if there is `category-name.html` entry end where it points to?

Comment: Is the category still a descendant of the category defined as the root of the store?

Comment: Have you tried to re-index Catalog URL Rewrite and Category Flat?

Comment: also, ensure mod_rewrite is installed and enabled in apache.

Comment: @WojtekT I went there and the issue was that the category for the current store was the one coming by default with Magento. I changed it to the first one I created and it worked.

Comment: @Ventus Tried that. No success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this. Magento was not detecting the other categories because they were other 'root categories' separated from the default coming with the installation. The solution is either change the current root category to another one in System - Manage Stores OR nest the other root categories under 'Default root category'.